# What way should I store an unlogged customer's cart?

Tags: database, flask, web, session, e-commerce

I have a flask ecommerce website in which I don't log in users.
Currently I user session for storing the user's cart.
My question is should I keep using session or should I store the cart in a db, and if so how should I identify a user.

Comment: Flask's [Session](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/quickstart/#sessions) should do for Anonymous users, otherwise have them sign up and save the cart on the database.

Comment: yes that's what i thought, i think i will just keep using flask session. Just wanted some opinions.

Comment: For such questions try the [Discord server](https://discord.gg/pallets). Also read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions) re opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Without being logged in or capture something identifiable other than IP if they drop off without ordering I think that's the end.

If you do want to store the cart and hope that a user comes back, you could obviously use IP address, but unless its static, it may not belong to the user in the future, which would (unlikely unless you're an extremely busy site) end up in someone new visiting with a previous visitors IP and being presented their cart.

But you could use IP address and some time period, a few days or whatever floats you're boat and if the IP returns within that chances are it'll be the same user. After the 'period' expires I'd say its time to bin that cart entry.